# Grep a pattern and ignore others

Tags: bash

I have an output with this pattern :

```
Auxiliary excitation energy for root 3:       (variable value)
```

It appears a consequent number of time in the output, but I only want to grep the last one.
I'm a beginner in bash so I didn't understand the "tail" fonction yet...

Here is what i wrote :

```
for nn in 0.00000001 0.4 1.0; do
for w in 0.0 0.001 0.01 0.025 0.05 0.075 0.1 0.125 0.15 0.175 0.2 0.225 0.25 0.275 0.3 0.325 0.35 0.375 0.4 0.425 0.45 0.475 0.5; do
a=`grep ' Auxiliary excitation energy for root 3:       ' $nn"_"$w.out`
echo $w"        "${a:47:16}  >> data_$nn.dat
done
done
```

With $nn and $w parameters.

But with this grep I only have the first pattern. How to only get the last one?

data example :

```
line 1 Auxiliary excitation energy for root 3:     0.75588889  
line 2 Auxiliary excitation energy for root 3:     0.74981555
line 3 Auxiliary excitation energy for root 3:     0.74891111
line 4 Auxiliary excitation energy for root 3:     0.86745155
```

My command grep line 1, i would like to grep the last line which has my pattern : here line 4 with my example.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you need. Could you rephrase the question providing sample data with multiple lines and specifying exactly what you want to capture?

Comment: @theMarceloR : I add an example of data, I Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last match, you can use:

```
grep ... | tail -n 1
```

Where `...` are your grep parameters. So your script would read (with a little cleanup):

```
for nn in 0.00000001 0.4 1.0; do
    for w in 0.0 0.001 0.01 0.025 0.05 0.075 0.1 0.125 0.15 0.175 0.2 0.225 0.25 0.275 0.3 0.325 0.35 0.375 0.4 0.425 0.45 0.475 0.5; do
        a=$( grep ' Auxiliary excitation energy for root 3:       ' $nn"_"$w.out | tail -n 1 )
        echo $w"        "${a:47:16}  >> data_$nn.dat
    done
done
```

Comment: @B_runo, if this is the answer, can you please accept it as such?